# Sending Enhanced apns in java

Tags: java, ios, push, voip

I am testing ios push in java, Its showing success but not receiving on device. Below is my java code. I have taken APNS certificate and token. 'messageSent' delegate is showing 
Sent message Message(Id=1; Token=3998989...; Payload={"aps":{"alert":"You have new message!"}}) Resent: false

```
public void sendEnhancedPush() {
    final ApnsDelegate delegate = new ApnsDelegate() {
        public void messageSent(final ApnsNotification message,
                final boolean resent) {
            System.out.println("Sent message " + message + " Resent: "
                    + resent);
        }

        public void messageSendFailed(final ApnsNotification message,
                final Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Failed message " + message);

        }

        public void connectionClosed(final DeliveryError e,
                final int messageIdentifier) {
            System.out.println("Closed connection: " + messageIdentifier
                    + "\n   deliveryError " + e.toString());
        }

        public void cacheLengthExceeded(final int newCacheLength) {
            System.out.println("cacheLengthExceeded " + newCacheLength);

        }

        public void notificationsResent(final int resendCount) {
            System.out.println("notificationResent " + resendCount);
        }
    };

    service = APNS.newService()
            .withCert(certificate_file, certificate_pass)
            .withProductionDestination().withDelegate(delegate).build();

    String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("You have new message!")
            .build();
    System.out.println("sending push");
    service.push(token, payload);

    Map<String, Date> inactiveDevices = service.getInactiveDevices();
    for (String deviceToken : inactiveDevices.keySet()) {
        Date inactiveAsOf = inactiveDevices.get(deviceToken);
        System.out.println("inactiveAsOf, " + inactiveAsOf);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with VOIP certificate? APNS requires a APNS certificate.

Comment: Yes that is APNS certificate, but device token is different for voip push. Normal push is working but voip psuh is not getting received from java code.